# How can I restrict a user from accessing certain pages?

Tags: python-3.x, django

There are pages "password_reset/" and "password_reset/done/". After filling out the form on the "password_reset/" page, there is a redirect to the "password_reset/done/" page. But if someone tries to access the page through the url, he will succeed. How to fix it.

```
path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
```

I tried to solve it this way, but something didn't work out.

```
class CustomPasswordResetDoneView(PasswordResetDoneView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        if referer != reverse('password_reset'):
            return HttpResponse(status=404)
        return render(request, 'registration/password_reset_done.html')
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using Mixins, Decorators or is_user_authenticated.